# Dar estilos a un Select CSS HTML (mover la flecha)

Tags: html, css, select, scss

Tengo un problema para dar estilos a mi select de mi página web.
Se ve así:
[image: Imagen de como se ven los selects]

El objetivo es que haya un padding entre la flecha y el final del select, quisiera mover la flecha o en su defecto agrandar ese espacio.
Por lo que vi, una forma es borrar todos los estilos predeterminados y crear el select a partir de eso. Capaz que hay alguna forma mas sencilla.
Adjunto mi código:

```
<div class="filters">
    <select class="filter">
        <option>Mercado</option>
    </select>
    <select class="filter">
        <option>Producto</option>
    </select>
    <select class="filter">
        <option>Fecha</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filter {
    font-family: "Ubuntu";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 150%;
    letter-spacing: -0.02em;

    padding: 4px;
    padding-left:8px;
    position: static;
    width: 169px;
    height: 38px;
    background: #adbcce;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 16px;
    margin-right: 8px;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
```

Comment: probá con `border-right: 8px solid transparent;` (o el tamaño que quieras)

Comment: Genial. Eso me funcionó, lo puse al final por el efecto cascada que me quita los bordes.